# The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client

Tags: google-oauth

I'm trying to organize access to Google Ads API.

I'm stuck at step 3 here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/oauth-web#step_3_-_generating_a_refresh_token

Namely, getting a refresh token.

I do this:

```
$ ./authenticate_in_web_application.py --client_secrets_path=/path/to/secrets.json
```

**secrets.json**

```
{
    "web": {
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "client_id": "some_client_id",
        "client_secret": "i_m_so_secret",
        "javascript_origins": [
            "https://avtomotokniga.ru"
        ],
        "project_id": "smpt-auth",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "https://avtomotokniga.ru/"
        ],
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
    }
}
```

When the script runs, it provides me with a hyperlink. I follow the link and find this:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/secret-uvml458ip15qmarbruq83bkmfbu3vilf.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=secret
```

**Problem**

Where **localhost:8080** is taken from?

I double-checked secrets.json and the credentials page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).

The Redirect URI is definitely there:

[image]

And it is saved. I opened and closed the page several times. And the json file is downloaded, that is the redirect URI is definitely taken into account.

How can I localize the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify `returnURL`, Google provides default as "/google-signin".

In .NET, `startup.auth.cs` file, add the URL as

```
//google OAuth 2.0 Client IDs 
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "456545-r6k8kf3gffghpoh13212s1fnkkfe.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ClientSecret = "VWuu45654655IeNUDEw32",
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/CONTROLLER/ExternalLoginCallbackFUNCTION")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by your screenshot, it's not there.
On your console, I see only https://avtomotokniga.ru/ in the redirect list.

You need to click the bottom "Add URI" button and add localhost:8080 there too.